# Golden numbers series

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Number is golden if it is divisible by the number before it. What is the max number of golden terms in a permutation of 1, 2...10,000?

I think the solution is that the max number of terms is half the total number of terms in the series, but I'm not sure how to confirm/prove this.

Comment: Source? Something about the question suggests to me that this could be from a contest. An easy one, but nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

To get as many as half of the numbers up to an even limit:

Start with an odd number, for instance $1$. Successively double it until you hit the limit, thus $1,2,4,8,...,8192$ in this case. Pick another odd number, such as $3$, to start a new sequence of doubling, rinse and repeat. You go through all the odd numbers, and then the even ones which are obtained from doubling the odd numbers are all golden.

Comment: For the other direction, call a number silver if it divides the number after it. Silver numbers are at most $n/2$.

Comment: @Eric, don't the definitions of golden and silver imply a one-to-one correspondence?

Comment: Yes, that’s the point